# How to convert single array value into multiple in php?

Tags: php

How to convert single array into multiple array in php. i have tried to convert it as single to multiple. Please check with my below code

```
Array
(
[value] => Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Option 4
Option 5)
```

Adding Status to each option

```
//Output should be 

Option 1 - Processing
Option 2 - awaiting payment..
```

Comment: Please try to explain more clearly what you are asking, at the moment it's hard to understand what you are asking, I'll try to help if you can clarify what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

If you want to create something like this:

`$array = new array('option1'=>'Processing', 'option2'=>'Awaiting Payment');`

Then you need to learn about [associative arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

If you mean something like this:

`$array = new array(new array('Option 1', 'Processing'), new array('Option 2', 'Awaiting Payment'));`

Then you need to learn about [multidimensional arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp).

I would suggest you to spend some time reading about arrays in [php's manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). I am pretty confident that if you give it a read, you will have your problem sorted out.